# $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n^2}$ converges $\implies \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need some help to solve the following problem:

*Show that if $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n^2}$ converges, then $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{a_n}{n}}$ converges.

I tried to solve it by using the Ratio Test, but got anything. Regards and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply Hölder's Inequality (Cauchy-Schwarz if you are not familiar with Hölder)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|a_n\cdot \frac1n \right | \leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2} \right)^{1/2} < \infty
$$
so the series is absolutely convergent.